# How to remove the global context from a nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, global-variables, node-modules

Any thoughts on how one would go about removing the global context from a nodejs module?

I'm not looking for a solution to the below problem, but if you need more context here you go.

I'm working on a project where my users are able to upload their own nodejs modules and, if it fits a predefined framework, it will run on our at periodic times through out the day. Obviously this is a major security concern. A good 90% solution would simply be removing the global context.

Comment: Due to the specified semantics of JavaScript, I don't believe this to be possible.

Comment: Why do you think they could do harm through the global context? If you really need user modules, run them in their own processes, with restricted rights (in a sandbox) and don't forget to kill them with a timeout.

Comment: Bergi: That might be a good solution for my problem, but I'm my intrigued by if you could limit the scope for now.  @pointy: what about blanking out all globals in the module?

Comment: @mcwhittemore by "blanking out" I presume you mean that you'd declare relatively local variables. Well, it would be somewhat tricky to do that dynamically, especially if the global state evolves and expands over time.  (Names of local variables have to be parse-time constants, and you can't add variables to a scope.)

Comment: @Pointy I think you'd have to have something that checked if that global context changed (aka, a new var was added) and then create a variable with the same name in the local context. That is, of course, after you've done this with all the original global vars in the first place. I'm going to try my hand at it (just for fun) and post what I find in a bit.

Comment: @mcwhittemore the problem is that it's possible for code with access to the global context to create new properties (global variables), but it's **not** possible to create new variables in other - oh wait I guess you could do it with `eval()`

Comment: @Pointy I'm hoping that broken sentence followed by vague mentions of `eval()` is a sign you are testing out an idea. :) I just proved to self that my idea first idea won't work. It creates a local property, but node doesn't seem to scan the local properties first but rather the global ones...

Comment: @mcwhittemore it seems like a pretty tricky thing; JavaScript really doesn't have any sort of "sandbox" notion, so trying to wedge one in is probably fraught with peril in many ways.

Comment: @Pointy yea, my guess is I'll have to write a "compiler" which looks at the code and throws errors when undesirables are found. But, alas, I did find out that if you straight up declare a property like `console` in a module it will scope overwrite the global. Working that angle a bit more.

Comment: I've set up a github for this question, if anyone want to see where I've gotten check it out (https://github.com/mcwhittemore/small-world). Also, I've been able to overwrite `require()`. Looking into why only `require()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you really need to run user-supplied modules in a separate process because an infinite loop will freeze any node process.

You should start with the [VM](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename) module:

- Read the file content (with [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback), not `require`).
- Define a new global object. You can choose to expose anything you want (and hide the rest).
- Run the user code.

Here's an example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    vm = require('vm');

function runCode(fileName) {
  var code = fs.readFileSync(fileName),
      sandbox = {
        console: console,
        setTimeout: setTimeout,
        clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
        require: require,
        module: module,
        exports: exports,
        process: process,
        Buffer: Buffer
      };

  vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox, fileName);
}
```

The user-supplied code will be able to access everything that I passed in the sandbox, as if it was in the global scope. In my case, I chose to expose almost everything from the real node.js global scope. You can chose what not to expose.

Also, you should check [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) if you want your solution to be secure.

Comment: know of any tutorials on defining the new global object. Nodejs docs leave something to be desired.

Comment: I don't know any, but I just edited my answer. Tell me if you need more info.

Comment: The page explicitly says:  `The vm module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code.`. You can probably try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2