# How do I run code in a VM while restricting access to all globals except the ones specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, global

If I have some code in a string, how can I run it without exposing any global variables.

The `vm` module appears to expose builtins:

```
const vm = require("vm");

vm.runInNewContext("console", {}); // No error, outputs an object
                                   // Expected it to error, since we are passing an empty context
```

---

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981885/how-to-remove-the-global-context-from-a-nodejs-module), whose solution isn't working for me (in Node v10.5.0).

Comment: @blex I'm not using `script.runInNewContext `, i'm using `vm.runInNewContext` https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options

Comment: Oops, my bad! I saw the same method name and mixed them up. [This discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15334) leads me to think that this is not a bug _"If you have a Dev Tools debugger attached, methods on console will be passed to the debugger. Otherwise they are no-ops."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `console` [happens to be an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641276/893780).

If you try other globals, like `require`, `process`, `__dirname`, `__filename`, etc, they will all cause an error to be thrown.

Comment: Hmm but I'm not getting an error with, say, `Symbol`, or `String` or `Object`

Comment: Those are part of the language.

Comment: So those are always accessible no matter what?

Comment: Looks like you can overwrite them in the context you pass: `vm.runInNewContext(..., { Symbol : undefined, console : undefined })`

Comment: @FireCubez If it's a proper VM, the builtins are new instances that are local to that realm. No need to make the inaccessible.